# How to select elements with a specific style of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a list:
[image: my_list]
where 3 'up's of the list are red(I've made it to Cell Expression as follows).

```
Cell[BoxData[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{StyleBox["up", StripOnInput -> False, 
   LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], ",", "right", ",", "up", ",", 
  StyleBox["up", StripOnInput -> False, 
   LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], ",", "down", ",", "down", ",",
   StyleBox["up", StripOnInput -> False, 
   LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], ",", "right", ",", "down", 
  ",", "left"}], "}"}]], "Output", 
CellChangeTimes -> {3.6183594862091923`*^9}]
```

Then, how can I pick out those elements with style red? Or more, with a specific style?
I tried to use `Select[list, Style[#,Red] &]` and `Cases[list, Style[#,Red] &]`, but yield nothing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific example. Assigining it to `test`.

The `InputForm`:

```
InputForm[test]
```

is

{Style[up, LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], right, up, Style[up, LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], down, down, 
 Style[up, LineColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], GraphicsColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], right, down, left}

So for this example you can extract the desired elements:

```
Cases[test, Style[__]]
```

Or get their positions (which may be an aim) and extract:

```
pos = Position[test, Style[__]]
Extract[test, pos]
```

Comment: I seem to understand. Those 'up's' style are more complex than just a `Red`, so I have to use BlankSequence?

Comment: Nice ... +1 ... could also use `Cases[test, _Style]`?